# problem with modsecurity in ajax - litespeed

Tags: php, ajax, litespeed

I have a PHP CMS which has setting section for the webstie. On these settings, it receives script codes automatically and then replaces into templates directly. 
The problem is that when the setting section is sent with Ajax for process, on the modsecurity server it blocks the post request with 403 error, because of the existence of script code on request data.
We can solve this issue with the code bellow on htaccess, but it deactivates the mod security which is not make sense:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

If anyone have solution for this issue that I could post the modification script to ajax without request blockage?
Is it possible to put those scripts on data with coding them?

DATA example :

```
stats: <img id='apfurgvizp' style='cursor:pointer' onclick='window.open("https://logo.samandehi.ir/Verify.aspx?id=539&p=dshwxlapfvl", "Popup","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, resizable=0, width=450, height=630, top=60")' alt='logo-samandehi' src='https://logo.samandehi.ir/logo.aspx?id=539&p=ujyshwlbsiy'/>
```

ERORR on send Ajax request :

```
 403 Forbidden Error
```

Server specifications :

Centos 7 Cloud Linux
CSF
CXS
modsecurity

CMS specifications :

pure PHP
OOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, disable entire mod_sec probably doesn't make much sense , but disable the single rule that cause the false-positive alert is.

you can use

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 1234567
</IfModule>
```

to disable that particular rule that cause the 403.

Comment: Thank you, does this not make the site admin panel less secure? Malicious scripts may be used in the box

Comment: yes and no ,  more strict rule also means more false-positive alert.  maybe you can check that rule , to see why it is hit , then you can workaround your code to avoid hitting it.

Comment: i check and see problem with script in this line code , if find way to encrypt code and send to ajax i think is solve but i don't know why